# Не могу найти нужный интерпретатор python3 для PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Работаю на Windows 10. Через установленный Bash на винде, создал виртуальное окружение для проекта venv, у которого интерпретатор находится по адресу `/mnt/c/django-sites/secondsite/venv/bin/python3`. Но DOM система Windows не отображает интерпретатор в списке настроек (см. скрин). Как мне указать нужный unix-адрес интерпретатора в PyCharm? Предлагает новый venv создать, но я уже пользуюсь готовым + все библиотеки уже установлены.

[image: скрин экрана с отсутствием интерпретатора]

Comment: Снизу в терминале с нужного интерпретатора вывел его адрес. Вот откуда я узнал нужный адрес интерпретатора.

Comment: Пробовали создавать новое окружение? (Чекбокс над тем, который вы выбрали)

Comment: Да, я могу создать новое, но задача стоит найти имеющееся, в котором уже есть все необходимые библиотеки.

Comment: В терминале пропишите команду `where python`. Это и будет путь к нему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас, похоже, **PyCharm Community**, для работы с **WSL** нужен **PyCharm Professional**

Comment: Да, вы правы насчёт версии. Видимо в этом и есть загвоздка